# Query 5 minute average from Prometheus

Tags: prometheus

I have a query to get used memory in Prometheus as a 0.0-1.0 percent. I can alert on this directly but don't want alerts on a short burst, only a high level over time or an average over time exceeding the limit.

I was hoping to do this in the query, but if AlertManger can do it that is acceptable, I just can't find how.

**The query**

```
(node_memory_MemTotal - node_memory_MemFree - node_memory_Buffers - node_memory_Cached) / node_memory_MemTotal
```

**The question**

How can I take the average over *i* minutes of that query result?

Answer (score 1):

I seem to have found a way to do this but I'm not sure it's the best.

```
(((node_memory_MemTotal offset 5m - node_memory_MemFree offset 5m - node_memory_Buffers offset 5m - node_memory_Cached offset 5m) / node_memory_MemTotal offset 5m) + ((node_memory_MemTotal - node_memory_MemFree - node_memory_Buffers - node_memory_Cached) / node_memory_MemTotal)) / 2
```

This uses the [offset modifier](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/basics/#offset-modifier) to take the same measurements 5 minutes ago and at query time, add then divide them to get the average.